# How to translate a Tableau FIXED LOD to Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a FIXED LOD with multiple dimensions that looks likes this:

```
{ FIXED [Customer ID], [Quarter], [Product Type] : SUM([Sales]) }
```

In Power BI I have wrote it as below using the example given in [this article](https://dataveld.com/2018/02/17/tableau-to-power-bi-fixed-lod-expressions/):

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Sales]), 
    ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Customer ID]),
    ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Quarter]),
    ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Product Type])
)
```

However it is not working as expected, could you help me understand the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Can you show what you're seeing and what you expect it to be? Are there any slicers or filters involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by editing my original expression, the following worked as expected:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Sales]), 
    ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Customer ID], 'Table'[Quarter], 'Table'[Product Type])
)
```